# MySQL Query Remove Duplicate Row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I have a database table in the format:

```
DataA | DataB | DataC | TimeStamp | UniqueID
```

Data may look like:

```
5 | 4 | 11 | 1/1/2014 | 1
5 | 4 | 2  | 2/1/2014 | 2
5 | 4 | 11 | 3/1/2014 | 3
3 | 6 | 7  | 4/1/2014 | 4
```

The problem is that I have duplicate entries where DataA-C are all the same (rows 1 and 3), but the TimeStamp (date data was recorded) and UniqueID are always different. The way that I am recording data (I do not have the option to change recording procedures) always leaves open the possibility of recording the same data twice.

How can I run a query that compares all of the Data columns to check if there is a duplicate row and remove the entry with the latest data. For instance row 1 was recorded first so I would want to remove row 3  and keep row 1

Thank in advance for your help.

Here is an option I have tried:

```
Select Line 
         DataA
        , DataB
        , DataC
FROM [Database].[dbo].[tbl_Data]
Where Line = 5
Group 
    BY Line 
     DataA
    , DataB
    , DataC
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: What is `Select Line` and `Group BY Line`? `Select Line Data, ...` is not proper syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM the_table
WHERE id IN (the select to return duplicated records' ids)
```

The select should be similar to this one

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
   the_table T JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM the_table 
    GROUP BY all your fields here
) sub ON T.id= SUB.id
```

Comment: What do T and Member stand for?

Comment: Corrected a bit. T in our case is alias (shorter name of thw_table)

Comment: So in the line below "From" are we joining the same table to itself?

Comment: OP wants to keep the one with the latest date.

Comment: @ben yes. we join the same table

Comment: @StanislavL Last thing. What do I insert for SUB.ID . Thanks for your help

Comment: SUB.id is id from the sub select. The subselect retrieves id's of records to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE UniqueId NOT IN (SELECT UniqueId FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM test
   ORDER BY TimeStamp) T1
 GROUP BY DataA, DataB, DataC)
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/884ab2/12)**

Comment: What do T1 and T2 stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Get **MAX** id change like below:

```
Select MAX(ID)
FROM [Database].[dbo].[tbl_Data]
Where Line = 5
Group 
    BY Line 
     DataA
    , DataB
    , DataC
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```